# What is a BNO(Business Network Operator) in Corda?

Tags: kotlin, corda

I am new to this.Could you please help me in understanding the concept in simple words?

Answer (score 1):

Corda Network involves a variety of machines and resources that need to be sized, deployed (on cloud or premise), architected, tested, managed and monitored to insure the stability and communication of the various participants in the Network.

From [Corda documentation](https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-enterprise/4.5/operations/project-planner/corda-planning.html#business-network-operator):

> The Business Network Operator is responsible for the infrastructure of the business network, they maintain the network map and identity services that allow parties to communicate, and - in many deployments - also operate the notary service.